# Controlling network connectivity from WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8, internet-connection

I have a WPF (not Windows Store) program written for .NET 4.0 in C#, which was ported to Surface Pro tablets. I need add the functionality to control network connections directly from the application in a similar fashion to the operating system's Networks dialog:

---

NETWORKS 
Airplane Mode     ON/OFF 
 

WIFI 
Nordic 
Belkin23          Connected 
64er23b 
Kenney

---

Popping up the exact same window inside the application is not an option, it doesn't conform with the application style and the users don't like the idea either.
What I need is a way to:

- obtain information about the available networks and their status (Ethernet, Wifi and 3G/4G)
- establish or tear down a connection to a network
- cancel an ongoing connection attempt
- capture related events (or if this is not feasible then use polling to get status periodically)

The feature must work with a non-admin user running the program.

So basically what I need is:

- a high level .NET library capable of these feats OR
- low level Win API functions I could use with PInvoke OR
- WMI queries which can achieve this OR
- anything else that works (and not dependent on hardware vendors)